# Lodash - Merge objects of two arrays on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, lodash

I have two arrays of objects.

```
arr1 = [
  {
    myName: 'Adam',
    mySkill: 'CSS',
  },
  {
    myName: 'Mutalib',
    mySkill: 'JavaScript',
  },
];

arr2 = [
  {
    myName: 'Adam',
    myWeight: '112',
  },
  {
    myName: 'Habib',
    myWeight: '221',
  },
];
```

The result I want is an array that contains objects of first array that have a matching property "myName" in second array, with the additional properties of the corresponding second array object.

```
result = [
  {
    myName = 'Adam'
    mySkill = 'CSS'
    myWeight = '112'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution below [groups](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) the [concatenated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) array (`arr1` and `arr2`) by `myName`, removes all groups that only contains one item using [reject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reject), and lastly use [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge) the resulting array.

```
var result = _(arr1)
  .concat(arr2)
  .groupBy('myName')
  .reject({ length: 1 })
  .map(_.spread(_.merge))
  .value();
```

```js
var arr1 = [
  {
    myName: 'Adam',
    mySkill: 'CSS',
  },
  {
    myName: 'Mutalib',
    mySkill: 'JavaScript',
  }
];

var arr2 = [
  {
    myName: 'Adam',
    myWeight: '112',
  },
  {
    myName: 'Habib',
    myWeight: '221',
  }
];

var result = _(arr1)
  .concat(arr2)
  .groupBy('myName')
  .reject({ length: 1 })
  .map(_.spread(_.merge))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

An alternative solution is to use [intersectionWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionWith) to get the intersection between two arrays and [assign](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) the missing values at the same time. Note the use of [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep) to promote immutability.

```
var result = _.intersectionWith(_.cloneDeep(arr1), arr2, function(x, y) {
  return x.myName === y.myName && _.assign(x, y);
});
```

```js
var arr1 = [
  {
    myName: 'Adam',
    mySkill: 'CSS',
  },
  {
    myName: 'Mutalib',
    mySkill: 'JavaScript',
  }
];

var arr2 = [
  {
    myName: 'Adam',
    myWeight: '112',
  },
  {
    myName: 'Habib',
    myWeight: '221',
  }
];

var result = _.intersectionWith(_.cloneDeep(arr1), arr2, function(x, y) {
  return x.myName === y.myName && _.assign(x, y);
});
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. in this case the native Js solution seems more simple

Comment: @MisterFresh check out my alternative solution.

Comment: accepted. simplified a bit : var result = _.intersectionWith( arr1, arr2, (x, y) => 
 x.myName === y.myName && _.assign(x, y)
) .. I thought the Comparator in IntersectionWith just returns a boolean, but apparently it works as a map function

Comment: @MisterFresh it is more likely a `forEach` than a `map`. I only used the short-circuit operation as a way to leverage the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative *native* JS solution using `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Object.assign` functions:

```js
var arr1 = [
    { myName: 'Adam', mySkill: 'CSS'}, { myName: 'Mutalib', mySkill: 'JavaScript'},
  ],

  arr2 = [
    { myName: 'Adam', myWeight: '112'}, { myName: 'Habib', myWeight: '221'}
  ],
  result = [];
  
arr1.forEach(function (o) {
    arr2.forEach(function (c) {
        if (o.myName === c.myName) result.push(Object.assign({}, o, c));
    })
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: yes my initial solution looks a bit like that. I was wondering if there was a simple way to do this with lodash but I guess not.

Comment: This of course works but it is an inefficient O(n^2) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table and push the object only if `myName` is common.

```js
var arr1 = [{ myName: 'Adam', mySkill: 'CSS' }, { myName: 'Mutalib', mySkill: 'JavaScript' }],
    arr2 = [{ myName: 'Adam', myWeight: '112' }, { myName: 'Habib', myWeight: '221' }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

arr1.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.myName] = { myName: a.myName, mySkill: a.mySkill };
});

arr2.forEach(function (a) {
    if (hash[a.myName]) {
        hash[a.myName].myWeight = a.myWeight;
        result.push(hash[a.myName]);
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do as follows with the help of a Map object.

```js
function mergeObjectsIfExists(p,a,b){
  var m = a.reduce((m,o) => m.set(o[p],o), new Map());
  return b.reduce((r,o) => m.has(o[p]) ? (r.push(m.set(o[p],Object.assign(m.get(o[p]),o)).get(o[p])),r)
                                       : r, []);
}

var arr1 = [{ myName: 'Adam', mySkill: 'CSS'}, { myName: 'Mutalib', mySkill: 'JavaScript'}, { myName: 'Jessuro', mySkill: 'Haskell'}],
    arr2 = [{ myName: 'Adam', myWeight: '112'}, { myName: 'Habib', myWeight: '221'}, { myName: 'Jessuro', myIQ: '150'}],
  result = mergeObjectsIfExists("myName",arr1,arr2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks. I'm not sure if this is more readable than the imbricated foreach loops though

Answer (score 0):

If using `lodash/fp` you could compose functions to achieve what you want. Assuming `myName` is your PK (or merge pivot), you could do:

```
const mergeByName = compose(values, spread(merge), map(keyBy('myName')));

> mergeByName([arr1, arr2])
[ { myName: 'Adam', mySkill: 'CSS', myWeight: '112' },
  { myName: 'Mutalib', mySkill: 'JavaScript' },
  { myName: 'Habib', myWeight: '221' } ]
```